# Imagebutton Picture is not showing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, innerhtml, imagebutton

I'm trying to replace within a `div` container an `Imagebutton` but the new picture is not shown.

This is the code from the aspx site before changing the picture:

```
<div id="pdfug" runat="server">
<asp:ImageButton ID="PDF_UG" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/PDF_gray64.png" style="text-align: center"/>
</div>
```

Everything is fine and the picture is shown. 
Now I change the content of the `div` container with this code:

```
pdfug.InnerHtml = @"<asp:ImageButton ID=""PDF_UG"" runat=""server"" ImageUrl=""~/images/PDF_red64.png""/>";
```

When I run the site the new Picture is not shown. In the source of the website I can see that the code was successfully replaced:

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_pdfug"><asp:ImageButton ID="PDF_UG" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/PDF_red64.png"/></div>
```

The picture is in the correct path, I can open it with

```
http://localhost:65277/images/PDF_red64.png
```

So where is the problem?

Comment: Try to remove cache with ctrl+f5

Comment: @NitinVarpe already tried different browsers and already removed cache. Also uploaded it to an IIS and there still the same problem

Comment: Have u checked with inspect element and opening that image link?

Comment: @NitinVarpe hmm it give's me `imageurl="~/images/PDF_red64.png"` back. I changed the code for `innerhtml` and deleted the `~/`, now when I inspect it shows `imageurl="images/PDF_red64.png` and this should be the right link because other pictures on the side which are shown have also `images/...`. But still my red picture is not shown...

Comment: @katz, we can not add directly server side tag into client side controls property. You can add either img tag ot input type="image" tag in div's innerHTML.

Comment: If I place a new `Imagebutton` on the side it gives me the code by inspecting `<input name="ctl100$MainContent$ImageButton4" id="ct100_MainContent_ImageButton4" type="image" src="images/PDF_red64.png"></input>` Seems that the `ImageButton` gets somehow converted?

Comment: @JayeshGoyani thanks for the info. the main goal is that the new image should also be a hyperlink to that pdf file. Would that be possible with an img tag or do I need javascript for that?

Comment: Why are you replacing the actual imagebutton code? Why not just change the same imagebutton's image URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just appending the control to the div container in the code behind?

```
ImageButton imgBt = new ImageButton();
imgBt.ID = "PDF_UG";
imgBt.ImageUrl = "~/images/PDF_red64.png";
pdfug.Controls.Add(imgBt);
```

Comment: Thanks that works for me but replaced `imgBt.Id` with `imgBt.ID`

Comment: Excellent. Yeah I just wrote it off the top of my head so forgot the correct casing. I have edited answer for future viewers.